# Pandas: df.diff() into new column in a multi column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which is like that:

| date | Col.A | Col.B | Col.C | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | 1 | 1 | ... |
| 2023 | 2 | 2 | 2 | ... |
| 2024 | 3 | 3 | 3 | ... |

And I want to add Columns where the Diff is calculated and looks like that afterwards:

| date | Col.A | Diff Col.A | Col.B | Diff Col.B | Col.C | Diff Col.C | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022 | 1 | nan | 1 | nan | 1 | nan | ... |
| 2023 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 | ... |
| 2024 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | 3 | 1 | ... |

I tried it like that, but it doesnt work

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', header=0).set_index(['date])

df.diff()
```

How can I do that in Pandas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rename new columns names by [`DataFrame.add_suffix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_suffix.html) for correct sorting without specify all columns names:

```
df = pd.read_excel('example.xlsx', header=0, index_col=['date'])

df = pd.concat([df, df.diff().add_suffix(' diff')], axis=1).sort_index(axis=1)

print (df)
      Col.A  Col.A diff  Col.B  Col.B diff  Col.C  Col.C diff
date                                                         
2022      1         NaN      1         NaN      1         NaN
2023      2         1.0      2         1.0      2         1.0
2024      3         1.0      3         1.0      3         1.0
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer. But I still get the same error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: found my mistake. your code works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.concat([df,df.diff().add_prefix('Diff ')], axis=1)
df = df.reindex(columns=sorted(df.columns, key=lambda x: (x.split(' ')[-1], x.split(' ')[0])))
df
###
   date  Col.A  Diff Col.A  Col.B  Diff Col.B  Col.C  Diff Col.C
0  2022      1         NaN      1         NaN      1         NaN
1  2023      2         1.0      2         1.0      2         1.0
2  2024      3         1.0      3         1.0      3         1.0
```